DeferrableSurface error when focus / taking photos on Android/Temi Robot with CameraX
Situation:
I made a custom Android app that runs on a Temi Robot.
The Android app moves the robot through a room and takes pictures with the onboard camera.
These pictures get saved onto the internal storage.
Technical details:

MinSdkVersion: 24
Target SDK version 33
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
Using CameraX version 1.3.0.
Kotlin version 1.8.22

Problem:
The app fails to take pictures at random positions/angles.
For example, when the robot is moving through a room it often faces a painted white wall. It seems that sometimes the camera fails to take a picture and the app crashes. I think this is because of a (auto)-focus problem of the white wall.
There are also other cases where this seems to happen, but they all have one thing in common. They are in difficult-to-focus positions. For example, a pure white wall or a close object that is in front of it.
Error
There is no clear error given. I posted the full error log below, but this does not seem to give any clue on how to fix it.
What I tried & other details
I first suspected memory issues, but after implementing garbage collection, and also taking over 50+ photos from different positions, this does not seem the problem. I also upgrade to the CameraX package version 1.3.0. Also without any result.
Interesting to note is that the DeferrableSurface message does not appear when the app succeeds in making a photo.
2024-04-22 18:47:45.033 23802-23828 DeferrableSurface       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  use count+1, useCount=2 androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@617af66
2024-04-22 18:47:45.033 23802-23828 DeferrableSurface       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  New surface in use[total_surfaces=3, used_surfaces=2](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@96c60c0}
2024-04-22 18:47:45.033 23802-23828 DeferrableSurface       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  use count+1, useCount=1 androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@96c60c0

Code
Starting camera
 private fun startCamera() {
        setUi()

        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)
            }

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
                .setFlashMode(ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_OFF)
                .build()

            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
                    .build()

                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture
                )
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

            binding.previewView.visibility = View.VISIBLE // Show camera preview
            binding.imageViewFace.visibility = View.GONE // Hide the photo view

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

Taking picture
private suspend fun takePhotoMan(): Boolean {
        val photoCaptureCompletion = CompletableDeferred<Boolean>()

        val outputdir = FileUtils.getOutputDirectory(this)
        val photoFile = File(
            outputdir,
            "$photoSessionId-$photoLocationsTaken-$photoNr.jpg"
        )

        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        Log.d(TAG, "Sleeping for 5 seconds before taking photo")
        delay(5000)
        Log.d(TAG, "Sleeping done for 5 seconds before taking photo")

        Log.d(TAG, "Taking photo $photoSessionId-$photoLocationsTaken-$photoNr")

        // cancel other photo requests
        imageCapture.camera?.cameraControl?.cancelFocusAndMetering()

        try {
            imageCapture.takePicture(
                outputOptions,
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                    override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                        photoCaptureCompletion.complete(false)
                    }

                    override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                        val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)

                        Log.d(TAG, "Resolution of the saved image is: - $savedUri")

                        // Get the resolution of the Bitmap

                        binding.imageViewFace.setImageURI(savedUri)

                        lastPhotoUri = savedUri.toString()

                        photoCaptureCompletion.complete(true)
                    }
                }
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error taking photo: ${e.localizedMessage}")
            photoCaptureCompletion.complete(false)
        }

        return photoCaptureCompletion.await()
    }

Error message
2024-04-22 18:47:35.066 23802-23802 PhotoActivity           com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Sleeping for 5 seconds before taking photo
2024-04-22 18:47:40.072 23802-23802 PhotoActivity           com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Sleeping done for 5 seconds before taking photo
2024-04-22 18:47:40.072 23802-23802 PhotoActivity           com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Taking photo 1713804422007-path_1713782278852_9830-0-1
2024-04-22 18:47:40.072 23802-23802 ImageCapture            com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  takePictureInternal
2024-04-22 18:47:40.073 23802-23802 CameraOrientationUtil   com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=0, isOppositeFacing=false, result=0
2024-04-22 18:47:40.073 23802-23802 TakePictureManager      com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Issue the next TakePictureRequest.
2024-04-22 18:47:40.102 23802-23828 Camera2CapturePipeline  com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  TriggerAf? AF mode auto
2024-04-22 18:47:40.102 23802-23828 Camera2CapturePipeline  com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Trigger AF
2024-04-22 18:47:40.103 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} Issue capture request
2024-04-22 18:47:40.103 23802-23828 CaptureSession          com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Issuing capture request.
2024-04-22 18:47:40.105 23802-23828 Camera2Cap...estBuilder com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  createCaptureRequest
2024-04-22 18:47:40.156 23802-23828 Camera2CapturePipeline  com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  checkCaptureResult, AE=CONVERGED AF =INACTIVE AWB=CONVERGED
2024-04-22 18:47:40.251 23802-23828 Camera2CapturePipeline  com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  checkCaptureResult, AE=CONVERGED AF =LOCKED_FOCUSED AWB=CONVERGED
2024-04-22 18:47:40.253 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} Issue capture request
2024-04-22 18:47:40.253 23802-23828 CaptureSession          com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Issuing capture request.
2024-04-22 18:47:40.258 23802-23828 Camera2Cap...estBuilder com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  createCaptureRequest
2024-04-22 18:47:41.484 23802-23828 DeferrableSurface       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  use count-1,  useCount=1 closed=false androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@617af66
2024-04-22 18:47:41.484 23802-23828 DeferrableSurface       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  use count-1,  useCount=0 closed=false androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@96c60c0
2024-04-22 18:47:41.484 23802-23828 DeferrableSurface       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Surface no longer in use[total_surfaces=3, used_surfaces=1](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@96c60c0}
2024-04-22 18:47:41.485 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  CameraDevice.onError(): 0 failed with ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE while in OPENED state. Will attempt recovering from error.
2024-04-22 18:47:41.486 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Attempt to reopen camera[0] after error[ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE]
2024-04-22 18:47:41.489 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: OPENED --> REOPENING
2024-04-22 18:47:41.492 23802-23828 CameraStateRegistry     com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Recalculating open cameras:
                                                                                                    Camera                                       State                 
                                                                                                    -------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                    Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]                         OPENING               
                                                                                                    -------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
2024-04-22 18:47:41.493 23802-23828 CameraStateMachine      com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  New public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=StateError{code=3, cause=null}} from OPENING and StateError{code=3, cause=null}
2024-04-22 18:47:41.493 23802-23828 CameraStateMachine      com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=StateError{code=3, cause=null}}
2024-04-22 18:47:41.496 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} Resetting Capture Session
2024-04-22 18:47:41.503 23802-23828 CameraCaptureSession    com.robotemi.sdk.sample              E  Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: 
                                                                                                    android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
                                                                                                        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2231)
                                                                                                        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1241)
                                                                                                        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:578)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl.close(SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl.java:476)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.CaptureSession.release(CaptureSession.java:526)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.releaseSession(Camera2CameraImpl.java:555)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.resetCaptureSession(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1329)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.closeCamera(Camera2CameraImpl.java:468)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.reopenCameraAfterError(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1827)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.handleErrorOnOpen(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1779)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.onError(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1754)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.CameraDeviceStateCallbacks$ComboDeviceStateCallback.onError(CameraDeviceStateCallbacks.java:121)
                                                                                                        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.notifyError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1629)
                                                                                                        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.lambda$oDs27OTfKFfK18rUW2nQxxkPdV0(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.-$$Lambda$CameraDeviceImpl$oDs27OTfKFfK18rUW2nQxxkPdV0.accept(Unknown Source:8)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:278)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:201)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:111)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:231)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:173)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2024-04-22 18:47:41.507 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} Releasing session in state REOPENING
2024-04-22 18:47:41.508 23802-23828 CaptureSession          com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  onSessionFinished()
2024-04-22 18:47:42.150 23802-23802 PhotoActivity           com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  position: Position(x=3.5866, y=-4.527, yaw=1.8288, tiltAngle=0)
2024-04-22 18:47:44.176 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} CameraDevice.onClosed()
2024-04-22 18:47:44.177 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} Camera closed due to error: ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE
2024-04-22 18:47:44.181 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} Attempting camera re-open in 700ms: androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback$ScheduledReopen@3e20a3c activeResuming = true
2024-04-22 18:47:44.924 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} Attempting to open the camera.
2024-04-22 18:47:44.925 23802-23828 CameraStateRegistry     com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  tryOpenCamera(Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]) [Available Cameras: 0, Already Open: true (Previous state: OPENING)] --> SUCCESS
2024-04-22 18:47:44.926 23802-23828 CameraStateRegistry     com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Recalculating open cameras:
                                                                                                    Camera                                       State                 
                                                                                                    -------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                    Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]                         OPENING               
                                                                                                    -------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
2024-04-22 18:47:44.927 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} Cancelling scheduled re-open: androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback$ScheduledReopen@3e20a3c
2024-04-22 18:47:44.927 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} Opening camera.
2024-04-22 18:47:44.928 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: REOPENING --> OPENING
2024-04-22 18:47:44.928 23802-23828 CameraStateMachine      com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  New public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null} from OPENING and null
2024-04-22 18:47:44.928 23802-23828 CameraStateMachine      com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null}
2024-04-22 18:47:44.933 23802-23828 UseCaseAttachState      com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  All use case: [androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-ae41370f-7c81-45db-9221-245993cff140215543379, androidx.camera.core.Preview-3742a4d1-5788-4c2d-ab91-dccb1ad4a51d80666178] for camera: 0
2024-04-22 18:47:45.020 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} CameraDevice.onOpened()
2024-04-22 18:47:45.021 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  {Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: OPENING --> OPENED
2024-04-22 18:47:45.023 23802-23828 CameraStateRegistry     com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Recalculating open cameras:
                                                                                                    Camera                                       State                 
                                                                                                    -------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                    Camera@b00f8e1[id=0]                         OPEN                  
                                                                                                    -------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
2024-04-22 18:47:45.023 23802-23828 CameraStateMachine      com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  New public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null} from OPEN and null
2024-04-22 18:47:45.023 23802-23828 CameraStateMachine      com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null}
2024-04-22 18:47:45.025 23802-23828 UseCaseAttachState      com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  All use case: [androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-ae41370f-7c81-45db-9221-245993cff140215543379, androidx.camera.core.Preview-3742a4d1-5788-4c2d-ab91-dccb1ad4a51d80666178] for camera: 0
2024-04-22 18:47:45.028 23802-23828 SyncCaptureSessionBase  com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  [androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl@7e21c3] getSurface...done
2024-04-22 18:47:45.028 23802-23828 CaptureSession          com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Opening capture session.
2024-04-22 18:47:45.033 23802-23828 DeferrableSurface       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  use count+1, useCount=2 androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@617af66
2024-04-22 18:47:45.033 23802-23828 DeferrableSurface       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  New surface in use[total_surfaces=3, used_surfaces=2](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@96c60c0}
2024-04-22 18:47:45.033 23802-23828 DeferrableSurface       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  use count+1, useCount=1 androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@96c60c0
2024-04-22 18:47:45.402 23802-23828 CaptureSession          com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Attempting to send capture request onConfigured
2024-04-22 18:47:45.402 23802-23828 CaptureSession          com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  Issuing request for session.
2024-04-22 18:47:45.402 23802-23828 Camera2Cap...estBuilder com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  createCaptureRequest
2024-04-22 18:47:45.407 23802-23828 CaptureSession          com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  CameraCaptureSession.onConfigured() mState=OPENED


2024-04-22 18:47:41.485 23802-23828 Camera2CameraImpl       com.robotemi.sdk.sample              D  CameraDevice.onError(): 0 failed with ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE while in OPENED state. Will attempt recovering from error.
Looks like a problem in the camera HAL implementation itself. The DeferrableSurface error in CameraX side is just a side-effect of this. Since the camera crashed, the previous surface is being released.
Does the problem still happen if ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY is not set to ImageCapture.Builder?

By the way, on a different note, imageCapture.camera?.cameraControl?.cancelFocusAndMetering() does not cancel a photo capture request, it only cancels a previous focus lock done with a CameraControl.startFocusAndMetering() invocation.
When CameraX locks focus for a MAX_QUALITY image capture, it automatically unlocks the focus after the capture is done. So this is not really required in your side.

@TahsinMasrur Thanks for your suggestions. I try to remove the maximize option and report to you ASAP.
Besides this, do you know why both of the onError and the tryCatch is not triggered?

The try catch is not invoked because the session closure and capture failure are happening asynchronously. The try block is checking the synchronous code execution only and by the time asynchronous failure happens, the try catch code is already executed and thus can't catch the exception.

As for the ImageCapture callback onError not being invoked, that might be a CameraX issue. This is just my assumption, but maybe CameraX does not explicitly make its image capture callbacks report onError when the camera HAL crashes or at least in this specific failure flow. But it might be a framework limitation too. Consider reporting this to the CameraX team at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=618491&template=1257717 for further investigation.

@TahsinMasrur Thanks for the clarification. I report this to the CameraX team. I don't think that this problem is fixable then by me then.

CameraX supports CTS/ITS compatible devices. I am not sure the Temi bots are CTS/ITS compatible, though. It's probably that they are doing something unconventional.

@Xi张熹 What camera method would you suggest using then for taking pictures?

You  will have better luck using camera2 directly.
